# Rails db:seed unknown attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, transactions

Here is a question.

I have an Rails project. When I want to clear my database and fill it with some test data I run:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

and I have an error:

`NoMethodError: undefined method login for #<User:0x007fecf46afe80>`

When I run separately:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

all goes fine.

Also all my actions in **db/seeds.rb** are wrapped in `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block.

I had to add `User.reset_column_information` in the top of my **db/seeds.rb** to make

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`

working.

I didn't have the same errors before without `reset_column_information`. Does somebody have any ideas why it's happen?

PS: after running `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` there is "missing" column in **db/schema.rb** and I can see this column in DB directly

Comment: please show your controller and model

Comment: I have same problem and model also `User`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class):

> reset_column_information() public
>
> Resets all the cached information
>   about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next
>   request.
>
> The most common usage pattern for this method is probably in a
>   migration, when just after creating a table you want to populate it
>   with some default values

You're `db:migrate` task changes the column information in the `users` table, but it looks like these changes are not properly written to the `db/schema.rb` file until the `rake` cammand finishes. Your `db:seed` task looks at `db/schema.rb` to see if the columns it needs exists, but this shows the schema as it was before the `db:migrate` unless you put it in a separate `rake` command or you run `reset_column_information()` before it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It sounds logically. But why does it happen? Why didn't it happen before?

Comment: Why does it happen? - See my answer. Why didn't it happen before? - I cannot say because you haven't given any information about "before". What has changed in your code or environment from before until now?